# How can I specify scaling settings in app.yaml correctly?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I'm deploying a node.js backend app on App Engine standard environment

the app.yaml file looks like this:

```yaml
runtime: nodejs12

env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: 'production'

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 100
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.9
```

but on deploy it says

```sh
RROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Frontend automatic scaling should NOT have the following parameter(s): [max_total_instances, min_total_instances, cpu_utilization.target_utilization] (or "version.env" should be set to "flex"
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: 'Frontend automatic scaling should NOT have the following parameter(s):
      [max_total_instances, min_total_instances, cpu_utilization.target_utilization]
      (or "version.env" should be set to "flex"'
    field: version.automatic_scaling
```

as far as the official docs are concerned, the automatic scaling part should work on standard if the instance is at least F1(which it is) so I don't get why it tells me that i should set the environment to flex and I cannot find anything about this issue on the webs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the official documentation on the [scaling options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#scaling_elements) for the standard environment on App Engine, it seems like you need to correct the parameters' naming.

In your particular case, you can make it work using the following:

```yaml
runtime: nodejs12

env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: 'production'

automatic_scaling:
  min_instances: 1
  max_instances: 100
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.9
```

I could reproduce this in the Cloud Shell and worked without issues.

Comment: Had the same issue and fixed it with params shared above.